# Ember-cli-pagination unable to print the remote paginated value in screen

Tags: ember.js, pagination, ember-data, ember-cli

I use [cli-pagination](https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination) for pagination. It is working fine but i am unable to set the page value = 0 instead it is always 1. Then while trying to print the value in screen it always print the id the model and other values are always empty. Please find the code sample below.

**model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr(),
  name: DS.attr(),
  status: DS.attr()
});
```

**Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ["page", "perPage"],
  page: 0,
  perPage: 2,

  //some actions
});
```

**Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import RouteMixin from 'ember-cli-pagination/remote/route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(RouteMixin, {
   model: function(params) {
     params.paramMapping = {
       perPage: "size"
     };
     return this.findPaged('book',params);
   },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    controller.set('books', model);
  }
});
```

**Template**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <h3>
        Books
    </h3>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
{{#each model as |book|}}
{{! your app's display logic}}
<h2>{{book.id}}</h2>
<h2>{{book.name}}</h2>
<h2>{{book.status}}</h2>
<h2>entered paged content</h2>
{{/each}}

{{page-numbers content=model}}
```

In the above code I am getting value for `book.id` but `book.name? &`book.status` is always empty even though getting value from backend.

Also by default `page` attribute is `1` but I want to set it to `0` because my backend API will accept page number `0`.

Comment: Have you tried ```page: null``` instead of 1? You can take that as a default case as pages count starts from 1.

Comment: @SuryaPurohit Thank you for your reply let me try but do you know why i am not getting the object value while printing

Comment: I checked this on my app but was able to get the page value 0, how are you getting the value btw? Also not able to get what you are saying by "In the above code I am getting value for book.id but book.name? &book.status` is always empty even though getting value from backend."

Comment: @SuryaPurohit you can see the controller code in the question i posted.I am setting "page: 0" in the controller. It is taking "perPage" property but not picking page attribute.In the backend i am getting value for all the attributes in the network tab i am able to see it but while printing it is always empty